# open db's transaction or not, any difference?

Tags: database, transactions

I think, when I access a berkeley db, each of my operation (no matter read or write) will be logged no matter the transaction is open or closed. Then, what's the difference of opening and not opening its transaction?

PS

When I insert or update data into the db, does each write operation committed directly into the db? or these operations just get cached, when the dbms make sure the transactions associating with these operations are ok, then commits them into the db? If so, this is what the transaction is for?

Comment: What do you mean by logged? What database system? What client library? (Some have different autocommit settings which muddle things up, not all databases have transactions.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/C/introduction.html#txnintro, and again, what do you mean by logged?

Comment: @Mat, I mean every operation accessing the db has been written into the db's log.

Comment: @Mat, what if I close the transaction? ACID won't be ensured, then the data in the db might not be correct?

Comment: Transactions are used to group a set of "actions" into a single work unit that is either saved completely or not at all. If you don't use transactions but need this grouping, then yes you can get logical corruption. You can still get logical corruption when you use transactions if you don't use them correctly.